# Run script every 4 minutes but don't run from 3:00 to 3:40

Tags: cron

**Issue**. In `cron`, what is the best and simplest way to configure run `example.sh` every 4 minutes in hour, but from 3:00 to 3:40 don't?

**I tried** this.

```
*/4 0-3 * * * example.sh
*/4 4-0 * * * example.sh
40,44,48,52,56 4 * * * example.sh
```

I believe there is a simpler way.

Comment: Start example.sh every 4 minutes and add functionality in example.sh to stop executing when the time is between 03:00 and 3:40.

Comment: As an alternative, you can run the script every 4 minutes round the clock and check whether it is "no run" time in the script and exit the script immediately when the clock is between 03:04 and 03:39.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes, I know, but this is not exactly what I want. And is ok `0-4`, or it should be `0-23`? Or is possible to do it with `4-3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow has a good answer similar to your problem:

- [Crontab run every 15 minutes except at 3AM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764150/crontab-run-every-15-minutes-except-at-3am/8764193)

In this answer a job runs every 15 minutes except blackout period from 3am to 4am at which time another job is run:

> ```
> # Every 15 minutes except for 3:00-3:59
> */15 0-2,4-23 * * * thejob
> # 3:15, 3:30, 3:45
> 15-45/15 3 * * * thejob
> # 3:00 dead
> 0 3 * * * otherjob
> ```

If you don't have another job to run during the blackout period remove the last two lines.

You can combine your two lines of:

```
*/4 0-3 * * * example.sh
*/4 4-0 * * * example.sh
```

With one line of:

```
*/4 0-2,4-23 * * * example.sh
```

Then for your last complicated line:

```
40,44,48,52,56 4 * * * example.sh
```

Replace it with:

```
40-59/4 3 * * * example.sh
```